# Adding a line to a heading

Tags: titles

Here is the skeleton of my LaTeX markup:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=1.25cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\name}{Name}
\newcommand{\hw}{1}

\title{\vspace{-50pt}
\Huge \name
\\\vspace{20pt}
\huge Class name\hfill Assignment \hw}
\author{}
\date{}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\textnormal{\name\hfill Assignment \hw\qquad\hfill}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

blah blah

\end{document}
```

which looks like this: [image: pdf]

I want to add the due date right under "Assignment 1", in the indicated location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `\huge Class...` line with:

```
\huge Class name\hfill \begin{tabular}{l}Assignment \hw\\Due date\end{tabular}}
```

[image: Blah blah]

If you would prefer to keep the baseline of "Class name" aligned to "Assignment" then use this instead

```
 \huge Class name\hfill \begin{tabular}[t]{l}Assignment \hw\\Due date\end{tabular}}
```

(Note the extra `[t]` option...)

Comment: +1 you might like to use `\begin{tabular}[t]....` (or just mention it)

Comment: @cmhughes that's a good idea

Comment: Also, suppressing the space: `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}...` might be a good idea